# Why are my processes that start from crontab limited to 0,7 cpu affinity.. but have full 0-27 affinity when manually ran?

Tags: cron

I've been having this issue for a couple weeks now where my processes have limited cpu affinity when triggered from crontab jobs.

When I manually run the startup scripts, they have full cpu affinity (0-27).

I've been checking process affinity with the taskset command.

Looking for any leads on where this configuration might be... or if this is expected behavior.

Comment: probably your cron process has a limited cpu affinity and the crontab jobs are inheriting that.

Comment: @ChrisDodd will check this in the morning.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Okay got out of bed and checked. This was the reason. Ty.